# Finding offsets on a 32bits integer

Tags: c

I have a very simple question but i can't resolve it.
There's an index from 0 to (2^32)-1 and i want to calculate an offset with this index like this :

0    to  (2^8)-1  => 0

2^8  to (2^16)-1  => 1

2^16 to (2^24)-1  => 2

2^24 to (2^32)-1  => 3

Can anyone give me the equation to do ?

Comment: Sidenote: Using `^` to designate "power of" is not a good idea. Better use either `pow(base, exp)` or (less confusing) `**`.

Comment: What do you **actually** want to accomplish? I suspect this is not what you really need, but what you **think** you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `i` is your 32 bit integer, this expression would work:

```
(i > 0xffffff? 3: i > 0xffff? 2: i > 0xff? 1: 0)
```

Actually, the last ternary `?:` operator is unnecessary, so the expression could be simplified to

```
(i > 0xffffff? 3: i > 0xffff? 2: i > 0xff)
```

Or you could remove the ternary operators and do only comparison and addition:

```
((i > 0xffffff) + (i > 0xffff) + (i > 0xff))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
uint32_t val, range, mask = (UINT32_C(1) << 16) - 1;

range = ((val > mask) << 1) | (((val >> 16) | (val & mask)) > 0xFFU);
```

Note this is not "offset", but gives the range/(number of octets used - 1).

On CPUs where compares/jumps are expensive (e.g. x86), this might be faster than the ternary approach.

I'll leave finding out why this is correct as a minor homework task. Just note: boolean expressions are guaranteed to yield `0` or `1`.

Comment: Why make `mask` a separate variable?

Comment: @owacoder: because I was too lazy to type twice. The compiler should optimize this.

Comment: Your example doesn't work for `val = 0x10000`. It returns `range == 1` instead of `range == 2`.

Comment: @owacoder: No: (simplified): mask is `0xFFFFU`, so `0x10000 > 0xFFFF == 1`. The leftshift (you could also use ` * 2`) yields `2`.

Comment: The mask is *not* `0xFFFFU`. It is `(2 << 16) - 1`, which equals `0x1FFFFU`. I just ran the code, and I think you have a typo. Try using `UINT32_C(1)` instead of `UINT32_C(2)`.

Comment: @owacoder: My bad! Of course it should have been `1 << 16`, not `2`! Edited, thanks